# Laravel, form posting using POST - if error, redirect forces GET?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

When posting a form using Laravel, I only want to use "POST" rather than "GET".
Most of the validation is done via javascript, but naturally server-side validation is also required.
If the server-side validation fails it needs to return the user back with errors, but to do that I use:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors("......
```

...but redirect happens via GET. Therefore I have to enable both GET and POST in the web route for these pages.

The problem is, the page involves editing a record that already exists, so in order to edit the form an ID is passed in, along with the "@csrf", via POST. Therefore when user has updated the details and submitted, if there is an error it tries to redirect user back to the page but if the page is not available via GET it can't access it.

```
    //validate data...
     $data = [
            'projectname' => 'required|string|max:255',                
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'string|min:6|required',
    ];

    $validator = \Validator::make($request->post(), $data);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return \Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        //Above redirect doesn't work because the previous page was a "POST"- only page
    }
```

Comment: without the get route, how are you displaying the form in the first place? Of course there need to be a `get` route to display the form, and then you `post` to some other route (get route and post routes are different routes) and if validation fails return back to the original get route with errors. Don't see any problem with that.  (If its an ajax call you can just return a json response, but I doubt you are dealing with ajax calls.)

Comment: Its normal that the redirect is using GET. You POST the form, it validates, errors go to the session, you get redirected (GET) to the form, where you can display the errors in the session...

Comment: @user3532758 not dealing with ajax. Actually, I've realised when the form is invalid and it returns, it gives a 404 because it's redirecting using "back", via GET. So the problem is even worse.

Comment: @Gert B I will update the post with more info...

Comment: Even after the edit.. You can use GET with a ID parameter. A redirect is a GET request. you don't lose the inputted fields if you use `old()` and the errors are available. There is really no reason to redirect using POST, and I believe it's not possible. You don't need to, and should not use a POST request to show the form in the first place.

Comment: Info updated in original post.

Comment: @James follow Gert's advice. Use GET to load form since loading the record into the form does not actually change the record's state. Use GET if it does not change state, POST if it would change the state. If you want to read up on when to use which, check this post [https://stackoverflow.com/a/2267847/3532758]  and other answers there.

Comment: Viewing a form is typically a GET operation since it will not alter the server state. Using a POST to view a form does not make any semantic sense.

Comment: Thanks all. I used GET to load the form instead.